# change in the color of the bars when scroll

Tags: javascript, svg, scroll

I need to add a change in the color of the bars when the scroll: when loading the page, the bars should be filled with green, and when using the scrolling, use the fill color on the red

Can this be done with simply do it on native javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var scrollTimeout;
window.onscroll = function() {
  clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
    svg.selectAll(".bar").style('fill', 'red');
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
       svg.selectAll(".bar").style('fill', 'steelblue');
    }, 500);
}
```

Ok. So to change color dynamically, you can use [HSL color](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp) and change first value. I use 0-125 period which is from red to green.

```
var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var color = 125 - 125 / scrollHeight * window.pageYOffset;
    svg.selectAll(".bar").style('fill', function(){return 'hsl('+color+', 100%, 50%)'});
}
```

also, if u need to tune color hue, just play with last two parameters

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!